# how to create table of content from character based style in MS Word 2013?

Tags: ms-word, tableofcontents

I have MS Word document which i used manually defined style named S11 "based on characters". Now i want to make table of content using text with S11 style.
I had created table of content using "paragraph based" style using predefined and also manual styles before.

But now when i want to create table of content in the "table of content option" dialogue box, I only see the paragraph based styles to choose from.

I don't want to use paragraph based style for my text because it applied to whole paragraph and i want some text within normal paragraph to be in S11 text.

for example you can think of some proverb that I used in content of a thesis and at the end of thesis i want to have list of all proverb used in the thesis and the page that I used them (I styled the proverbs in S11 style to bold them from normal text inside the content).

Is ther any way?

Comment: The TOC field does not support including character styles. Would using an Index be an option? That would require to mark each quote as an index entry (and you can't have a 'regular' index then).

Comment: I concur with @Dirk Vollmar re. the TOC field, and an Index looks like a better fit for your requirement than a TOC, but if necessary you can also base a TOC field on TC field entries, which means that you can have both a TOC *and* an index.

Comment: Indeed, inserting TC fields for each quote and creating a TOC field based on the TC fields probably is the best option.